# This is the best way to create a range filter in SQL with php IF statement?

Tags: php, sql

So I want to create a range filter and I wondering if this is the best way to create if statement. Is there cloud go anything wrong?

So here is my code:

```
$from = "20";
$to   = "21";

$bind_value = array();

if ( !empty($from) && !empty($to) && $from < $to ) {
        $myquery .= " WHERE rand_number BETWEEN :from AND :to";
        $bind_value = array_merge($bind_value, array(
        'from'=>"$from",
        'to'=>"$to",
        ));
    }
    else if (!empty($from) && empty($to)) {
        $myquery .= " WHERE rand_number >= :to ";
        $bind_value = array_merge($bind_value, array(
        'to'=>"$to"
        ));
    }
    else if (!empty($to) && empty($from)) {
        $myquery .= " WHERE rand_number <= :from ";
        $bind_value = array_merge($bind_value, array(
        'from'=>"$from"
        ));
    }
    else {
        $myquery .= "";
    }

$stmt = $connpdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM my_table ".$myquery."");

// Bind values
foreach($bind_value as $key=>$search){
   $stmt->bindValue(':'.$key, $search,PDO::PARAM_STR);
}

$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: `$myquery .= "";` Will this not produce error?

Comment: Using `empty` will disallow the usage of `0` as a valid integer.

Comment: PDO is not a magic wand that would prevent SQL injection by mere presence. This code IS open to SQL injection, no matter which driver is used.

Comment: @YourCommonSense For sure, but I will not use php strings ($from, $to) in $myquery. I will use bindvalue as well. This is just a demonstration to easier explanation

Comment: I don't see how it makes an easier explanation. But I see another VERY BAD example posted on the Internet, so more people can learn the bad way.

Comment: @kviktor1230 `$connpdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM my_table ".$myquery."");` looks weird to me. So you are concatenating the string beforehand? Also, your elseif looks ok looking at the no. of conditions possible.

Comment: Also, what are the lower and upper limits of `rand_number` possible? That can simplify your code.

Comment: and now you need to update the answer as well, because it contains the bad code copied from your question.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly it would work the only thing is the last bit would give an error as there is no validator on the end of the query.

the else statement would resolve in:

```
select * from my_table where rand_number
```

this errors in sql, to make it correct you would need to remove the where statement completly:

```
select * from my_table
```

Besides this you can write the code slighly easier:

```
if ( !empty($from) && !empty($to) && $from < $to ) {
    $myquery .= " WHERE rand_number BETWEEN :from AND :to";
    $bind_value = array_merge($bind_value, array(
    'from'=>"$from",
    'to'=>"$to",
    ));
}elseif (!empty($from) && empty($to)) {
    $myquery .= " WHERE rand_number >= :to ";
    $bind_value = array_merge($bind_value, array(
    'to'=>"$to"
    ));
}elseif (!empty($to) && empty($from)) {
    $myquery .= " WHERE rand_number <= :from ";
    $bind_value = array_merge($bind_value, array(
    'from'=>"$from"
    ));
}   

echo $myquery;
```

The numbers can be strings or integers, this will not matter for the sql statement